# S3 Bucket From a Different Account Invoking My Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

The account who's S3 bucket I am looking to invoke my lambda function has given me access to assume roles. If I attach the role to the lambda functions execution role will this invoke my lambda function? I dont think this will work because whenever I have invoked lambda's from S3 in the past, I needed to add the notification configuration to my S3 bucket. Am I able to do this on the bucket that I do not own ?

I am looking to begin testing today and wanted some insight.

Thank you.

Comment: *"If I attach the role to the lambda functions execution role will this invoke my lambda function?"* - that is not how anything works :D you cannot attach a role to a role and it will certainly not trigger any lambda. Yes, you need to specify the notification configuration and yes, you can do this on buckets you do not own as long as you have been granted the relevant permissions.

Comment: You do not assume roles "on resources". The only thing you can assume are roles, period. That is what roles are for. And those roles may have permissions that enable you to do things.

Comment: okay thanks. I was assuming the role with boto3 and tried to apply the put notification configuration on my lambda from the assumed role client and I was denied access.